# Windows bazel says python is not an executable when building tflite

Tags: python, c++, windows, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build c++ tflite for windows using bazel by following the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows). So far I've installed everything it want's me to and added them to `PATH`. Then I cloned the github repo and checked out to `r2.12` branch.

Then I ran `python ./configure.py` and selected default for everything (said yes to override eigen strong inline). When doing so it declared that my python is located on `C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe`.

After that running `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite` on the directory where I've cloned tensorflow in cmd casuses this error:

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=117
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  'build' options: --python_path=C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --define framework_shared_object=true --define tsl_protobuf_header_only=true --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone -c opt --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --noincompatible_remove_legacy_whole_archive --enable_platform_specific_config --define=with_xla_support=true --config=short_logs --config=v2 --define=no_aws_support=true --define=no_hdfs_support=true --experimental_cc_shared_library --experimental_link_static_libraries_once=false --incompatible_enforce_config_setting_visibility
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages --python_path=C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --define=override_eigen_strong_inline=true
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --deleted_packages=tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/benchmarks,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/python_binding,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/transforms,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/python_tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/ir,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/analysis,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/jit,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/lhlo_to_tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/lhlo_to_jitrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_corert,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_tfrt_data,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/saved_model,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/transforms/lhlo_gpu_to_tfrt_gpu,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/conversion,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/kernel,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/opdefs,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/runtime,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/util,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/cpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/cpp_tests/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/run_handler_thread_pool,tensorflow/core/tfrt/runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model,tensorflow/core/tfrt/graph_executor,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model/tests,tensorflow/core/tfrt/tpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/utils
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:v2 in file c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define=tf_api_version=2 --action_env=TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:windows in file c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --copt=/W0 --host_copt=/W0 --copt=/Zc:__cplusplus --host_copt=/Zc:__cplusplus --copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --host_copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --features=compiler_param_file --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --cxxopt=/std:c++17 --host_cxxopt=/std:c++17 --config=monolithic --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --copt=-DNOGDI --host_copt=-DNOGDI --copt=/Zc:preprocessor --host_copt=/Zc:preprocessor --linkopt=/DEBUG --host_linkopt=/DEBUG --linkopt=/OPT:REF --host_linkopt=/OPT:REF --linkopt=/OPT:ICF --host_linkopt=/OPT:ICF --verbose_failures --features=compiler_param_file --distinct_host_configuration=false
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file c:\users\asus\desktop\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define framework_shared_object=false --define tsl_protobuf_header_only=false --experimental_link_static_libraries_once=false
INFO: Repository local_config_python instantiated at:
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:15:14: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace2.bzl:957:19: in workspace
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace2.bzl:104:21: in _tf_toolchains
Repository rule python_configure defined at:
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl:298:35: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_python':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 271, column 40, in _python_autoconf_impl
                _create_local_python_repository(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 212, column 22, in _create_local_python_repository
                _check_python_bin(repository_ctx, python_bin)
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 145, column 25, in _check_python_bin
                auto_config_fail("--define %s='%s' is not executable. Is it the python binary?" % (
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/remote_config/common.bzl", line 12, column 9, in auto_config_fail
                fail("%sConfiguration Error:%s %s\n" % (red, no_color, msg))
Error in fail: Configuration Error: --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH='C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe' is not executable. Is it the python binary?
ERROR: C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:15:14: fetching python_configure rule //external:local_config_python: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 271, column 40, in _python_autoconf_impl
                _create_local_python_repository(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 212, column 22, in _create_local_python_repository
                _check_python_bin(repository_ctx, python_bin)
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 145, column 25, in _check_python_bin
                auto_config_fail("--define %s='%s' is not executable. Is it the python binary?" % (
        File "C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/remote_config/common.bzl", line 12, column 9, in auto_config_fail
                fail("%sConfiguration Error:%s %s\n" % (red, no_color, msg))
Error in fail: Configuration Error: --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH='C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe' is not executable. Is it the python binary?
INFO: Repository local_execution_config_python instantiated at:
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:15:14: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace2.bzl:957:19: in workspace
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace2.bzl:94:27: in _tf_toolchains
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/toolchains/remote_config/configs.bzl:6:28: in initialize_rbe_configs
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/toolchains/remote_config/rbe_config.bzl:158:27: in _tensorflow_local_config
Repository rule local_python_configure defined at:
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl:279:41: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository go_sdk instantiated at:
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:23:14: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/asus/desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace0.bzl:134:20: in workspace
  C:/users/asus/_bazel_asus/ddsftcyc/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_extra_deps.bzl:36:27: in grpc_extra_deps
  C:/users/asus/_bazel_asus/ddsftcyc/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/private/sdk.bzl:431:28: in go_register_toolchains
  C:/users/asus/_bazel_asus/ddsftcyc/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/private/sdk.bzl:130:21: in go_download_sdk
Repository rule _go_download_sdk defined at:
  C:/users/asus/_bazel_asus/ddsftcyc/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/private/sdk.bzl:117:35: in <toplevel>
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite' failed; build aborted: Configuration Error: --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH='C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe' is not executable. Is it the python binary?
INFO: Elapsed time: 224.163s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (32 packages loaded, 15 targets configured)
```

Looking at the main error part of this output : `ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite' failed; build aborted: Configuration Error: --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH='C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe' is not executable. Is it the python binary?`

I checked whether python was there or not, it indeed is. Simply running `C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe` in cmd indeed opens python.

So I checked the internet for some solutions, I've removed the "python installers" from my system, added python to PATH, tried the same steps with tensorflow source zip instead of cloning it, nothing works.

Some people suggested chaning some stuff inside the `py` directory of tensorflow but it didn't work aswell.

Why is this happening? What causes bazel to not see python even though it's there? How can I fix this and get a build with windows?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? If you have, please share.

Comment: @HJLebbink No, I've tried another computer and it worked there, presumably a different version windows but I don't remember the specifics.